# is there a way to know how long does it take to prolog's inference engine to get a respones for a query?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, inference-engine

I am trying to find out which way of finding an answer to a query in prolog is faster.

For instance, if

`employee('John',23).
 rule2('John', 'Likes to play basketball').`

if faster than:

```
employee('John', '23').
rule2(employee('John,_),'Likes to play basketball').
```

Comment: Please see the related question: [How to test the performance of a Prolog program?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4582822/1613573)